# dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-7.0 (--install)

Tags: package-management, dpkg, debian

I have an issue with install deb files

i used `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/virtualbox-7.0_7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb`

to install it

```
    dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-7.0 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.6+22.04.20220217-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-7.0
```

it's installed but not open !!

how can I fix this?

Comment: Your issue is "dependency problems - leaving unconfigured" where you need to install the dependencies as well.  Try running `sudo apt install -f` or try installing the deb file itself from the directory that you downloaded it to and running it as `sudo apt install ./<debfilename>.deb`

Comment: thank you bro   it's already installed sudo apt install ./<debfilename>.deb working    but i want to install the files

Comment: Use `sudo apt install --reinstall ~/Downloads/virtualbox-7.0_7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb` instead ... APT will download and install dependencies as long as it can find them in its repositories list, but `dpkg` wont do that.

Comment: yes i used sudo apt install ~/Downloads/virtualbox-7.0_7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb

Comment: how can i make the question is solved ?

Comment: You can actually write your own answer below and mark it as the right answer after 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look the logs, there are some logs that virtual box depends on some packages such as **libqt5help5**.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

this solved my problem.